# How to deliver parameters to Glide Callback method?

Tags: android, android-glide, baidu-map

I use Baidu Map to display shops got from server, containing picture url. I use Glide to set Icons for map.

**Here is my method which using to add Marker to map.**

```
private void setMarks(List<ShopList> shops) {

    for(ShopList shopItem : shops){
        double latitude = shopItem.getLat();
        double longitude = shopItem.getLng();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);


        String shopName = shopItem.getName();
        OverlayOptions textOption = new TextOptions()
                .text(shopName)
                .fontSize(50)
                .position(latLng);
        mBaiduMap.addOverlay(textOption);


        Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext())
                .load(shopItem.getCategory_image())
                .asBitmap()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_shop_image_loading) 
                .error(R.drawable.ic_shop_image_load_error)    
                .override(SizeUtils.dip2px(mContext,128),SizeUtils.dip2px(mContext,128)) 
                .centerCrop()                                                            
                .into(target);                                        
    }
}
```

**Here is Glide Callback code.**

```
private SimpleTarget<Bitmap> target = new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
        BitmapDescriptor descriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resource);
        Marker marker = (Marker) mBaiduMap.addOverlay(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(descriptor));
        mMarkers.add(marker); 
    }

};
```

I could not deliver parameter of latLang, so I can not init Marker in onResourceReady, can not add Marker to mMarkers also. What can I do to relate latLang to specific Bitmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your custom `Target`.

```
public class MyTarget extends SimpleTarget<Bitmap> {

    private final LatLng latLng;

    public MyTarget(LatLng latLng) {
        this.latLng = latLng;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(final Bitmap resource, final GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
        // use your `latLng`
    }
}
```

And use this way:

```
Glide.with(...)
    ...                                                    
    .into(new MyTarget(latLng));
```

Comment: Thanks to answer. I have concept of Encapsulation in-depth.